# How to filter data base which contains map Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore, filtering

[image: Firebase DB]

Hi everyone.
I have a question. How I can filter my database via map inside FirebaseFirestore in Flutter.
Let's say, If I want to filter my database using "spotProperties", I can do it by writing:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('spots')
        .where('spotProperties', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 'gaps')
        .snapshots().listen((spots){
      mapRecords(spots);
    });
```

And it works fine.

How can I do it the same, if I would like to filter my database using "countryName" or "cityName"? I was trying to fix this using many ideas, but no results. For Your info - "cityName", "streetNumber" etc. are located inside map "spotAddress".

Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

```
   .where("spotAddress", isEqualTo: {
                          "countryName": "India",
                          "cityName": "delhi",
                          "streetNumber": 23
                        })
```

Comment: One more question. Can I use only "countryName" or I need to pass all map values? I would like to use only one of the value and filter it by: country or city or street.

Comment: No, you don't need to pass all map values.

Comment: Thanks. But to be honest it is not working :(

Comment: Can you try all map values?

Comment: I did it also, no positive result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that this works:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('spots')
        .where('spotAddress.countryName', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 'U')
        .snapshots().listen((spots) {
      mapRecords(spots);
```

Main problem was, that when I added cityName or countryName to firestore i didn't trim white spaces. When I was trying to call data, there was a need to have one blank space on the beggining.